# Vray material to Blender

Tags: texturing, materials

I want to convert 3ds max vray material to blender,however the nodes are quite different.If I want to achieve a two-sided material in vray,I use the node Vray2sidedmtl.In blender I can use mixshader and backfacing.But there is a translucency Tex in Vray2sidedmtl so that I can determines which side (front or back) relative to the camera is more visible in the rendering process,how can I do this in Blender?

If someone tells exactly how to transform vray material to blender,it will be much better.